# Printf and warning with #define string

Tags: c++, string, printf, warnings, c-preprocessor

I am using Qt creator, and it generates this error:

> "warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*',

but argument 2 has type 'const void*' [-Wformat]"

The console app is working, but I am interested if there is way to avoid this error, just interested

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

bool isOpen(FILE *file);
void print(const void *text);

#define FILE_IS_OPEN "The file is now open"

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("This.txt", "w");

    if(isOpen(f))
    print(FILE_IS_OPEN);

fclose(f);
return 0;
}

bool isOpen(FILE *file) { return file != NULL ? true : false; }
void print(const void *text) { printf("%s\n", text); }
```

Comment: Why does `print` take a `const void*` argument at all?

Comment: Change the signature to `print(const char* test);`

Comment: The error message is quite clear. A lot of this code should really change if you have C++ available, though. Use `std::fstream` so you don't have to close it yourself. Use `std::cout` so you don't have to worry about matching types. Use `std::string` and change `FILE_IS_OPEN`, since a macro is definitely not the best way to have  a constant string. Get rid of `isOpen` and use `.is_open`, and swap out `print` for a simple `std::cout <<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change

```
void print(const void *text);
```

to

```
void print(const char *text);
```

The same applies in function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Format specifier `%s` indicates that you're trying to output a string to console, so it requires you to give the address of the string which is nothing but `char *` here,
you can cast it to `(char *)text` and pass it to `printf`.

Also you can't output the contents of a `void *` pointer they have to any of the primitive data types.